# Bash return permission denied error when I redirect the output of ls to a file

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I'm currently studying shell commands, one of the exercises consists in creating a structure with various directories and subdirectories.

I wrote `ls -laR > hello`, it was supposed to create a text file named `hello`.
However, I get the following message `bash: hello: permission denied`, even when I type sudo in the beginning.

The command worked in another Linux distribution.
Also, I used a few minutes ago `ls -la` in the directory where I want to create the file and it gave me this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 26 10:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 26 10:56 ..
```

According to the first triad I have writing privileges?

Comment: `ls -laR > hello` works on my Ubuntu if I issue it in my home dir. Best you can do is show us the permissions of the directory you are in :)

Comment: Maybe reason is in place where you are trying to create that files? I tried this on my Xubuntu 13.10 and it was working in my home folder, but directly on disk (/) i had the same message, also sudo didn't help.

Comment: What path you are? Is the partition mounted as read-only?

Comment: @Rinzwind I posted the directory permissions.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $USER $PWD`?

Comment: Why don't you tell us **where** you are executing that command?

Answer (score 17):

Because root is the owner of the directory where you want to create `hello` file and users from the same group and other users doesn't have permission to write in that directory, you will get `bash: hello: permission denied` error when you run `ls -laR > hello`.

Moreover, you will get exactly the same error when you run the same command using `sudo` in front of it. This because **output redirection (the `>` operator) is done by the shell**, not by `ls`, so `sudo` has no effect upon it. `sudo` has effect only on `ls  -laR`. To prevent this, you have to login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Then you can use redirection:

```
ls -laR > hello
```

Otherwise, you can run your bash command in a subshell with root privileges:

```
sudo bash -c "ls -laR > hello"
```

Finally, another option, instead to use redirection via the `>` operator, you can use `tee` command:

```
ls -laR | sudo tee hello
```

You don't have to use in this case `sudo` for `ls` command because users from the same group with root and all other users have read and execution permission in that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Either put the hello file in a writable directory like with:

```
ls -laR > /tmp/hello
```

or, if you really want to create a file in a directory you don't own, run:

```
sudo sh -c "ls -laR > hello"
```