# sending message to printk buffer from user space -- not working

Tags: command-line, kernel

Actually i want my driver messages to reach my terminal for debugging purpose. So i just try to check by following below link.

I refred following link :--
http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing

I am using a ubuntu in side vmplayer virtual machine. Ubuntu is running in terminal mode inside virtual machine. 
I am trying to send some message to kernel printk buffer, buts echo command fails.

klog demon is also running i confirmed with following command .

```
ps aux | grep klogd
```

Cat command on proc printk entry :---

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4 4 1 7
```

run echo command :---

```
#sudo echo "<1>Writing critical printk messages from userspace" >/dev/kmsg
```

But i am not able to get the message on the terminal. I am getting following error when runs above command :--

```
-bash: /dev/kmsg: Permission denied
```

Please suggest how to print on console ?

my actual requirement is to ... send messages of printk() in my driver ... directly to my console.  I  am just testing here from my console that messages of low priority reaches console or not .

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
echo "<1>Writing critical printk messages from userspace" | sudo tee /dev/kmsg
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/382546/147044) to understand why.

Comment: my actual requirement is to ... send messages of printk() directly to my console. But here you are using tee to direct same message to console & to /dev/kmsg ... is this way of using tee option is right ? I  am just testing here from my console that messages of low priority reaches console or not .

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: how this post is right then .. ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972155/linux-kprint-messages-on-console

Comment: In the stackoverflow post, the command is likely issued in a root shell (as hinted at by the `#` prompt). You cannot achieve the same thing simply by prepending `sudo` to the command, since the elevated privileges apply to the `echo` command (which doesn't need them), but do not flow through to the redirect to `/dev/kmsg` (which does). Using `echo " ... " | sudo tee /dev/kmsg` is one way to work around that - you could also wrap the whole command inside a shell command e.g. `sudo bash -c 'echo "<1>Writing critical printk messages from userspace" >/dev/kmsg'`